# Packages containing 'dfsg' in version number are causing issues

Tags: debian, linux-mint, package-management, python

I am running the same Python software under both Mint 13 and Mint 17.1 – both are 64-bit. Prior to 64-bit operation the software was running on Mint 13 32-bit. On 64-bit Mint 13 everything works as expected, however on Mint 17 some of the boxes are not rendered correctly. Going through the Package Manager both `python-wxversion` and `python-wxgtk2.8` are the same version bar the ones on Mint 17.1 contain `dfsg` in their names.

Checking on the internet it says that this indicates that the package has been stripped of any files that don't meet the Debian Free Software Guidelines. Is there any way I can force the Mint 17.1 system to install the same package as the Mint 13 one as I do not want to potentially spend days working around a problem that I feel should not be there.

Comment: It might be  helpful to mention what specific problems you are seeing.

Comment: In two areas I have a number of wx.Button (s) within a wx.StaticBox. The StaticBox is not being rendered on Mint 17.1. I do not want to spend time going through all the various options until this issue is resolved as it makes the Front End look rather amateurish!

Answer (score 4):

The files removed in these `+dfsg` packages are:

- Windows DLLs
- built-in copies of libraries provided elsewhere (`libexpat`, `libjpeg` and the like)
- `editra`, which is available in its own package
- various Flash files
- some samples from TV shows

As such I don't think any of the removals would cause the symptoms you're seeing.

In any case you can try simply copying the package archives (`.deb` files) from your Mint 13 system and installing them in your Mint 17.1 system; if anything breaks you can restore it with `apt-get upgrade`. (Note that generally speaking downgrades aren't supported, but they tend to work quite well.)

Comment: Rebuilding from source generally produces better results.

Comment: I have searched through the Mint 13 file system and the only .deb files are ones related to packages installed outside the Synaptic Package Manager

Comment: After some researchI installed the previous versions with "sudo apt-get install PackageName=VersionRequired". However this caused dependency problems. So not really any further forward!

Comment: Any further thoughts anyone? We want to go to Mint 17.1 but this issue is a show stopper!

Comment: You could try to rebuild from source as suggested by [Faheem Mitha](http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/4671/faheem-mitha) and see if the resulting packages work; start with `apt-get install devscripts`, then `dget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/wxwidgets2.8_2.8.12.1-6ubuntu2.dsc` (assuming that's the version in Mint 13), `cd wxwidgets2.8-2.8.12.1`, `dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc` and install anything the latter asks for before repeating it.

Comment: Thank you for response. By repeating it I assume you mean "sudo apt-get install PackageName=VersionRequired"?

Comment: No, I meant repeating `dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc`; and I forgot to mention that you'd need to install the resulting `.deb` files generated in the parent directory.

Comment: 'code'dpkg-buildpackage'code' came back with 23 modules that needed amending. Recalling that a similar situation lead to dependency hell three months ago and the system had to be re-built I have put this on hold for now. Thank you for you efforts...